# If-statement with int: Java believes i want to convert to boolean

Tags: java, int, boolean

I'm writing a method in a class that retrieves an array and a set value from main. The aim is to locate the position of that given value and return this to main (if the value does not exist in the array it returns -1).
To my problem: when i run my code Java says: int cannot be converted to boolean. And points me to the if-statement in the code below. I tried switching the "="-sign to a ">=", and then it runs smoothly (but then it doesn't work like it's supposed to...). 
Can anyone see why it thinks i want to convert it to a boolean?

```
    public static int containsIntElement(int[] A, int val)
    {
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(A[i] = val)
            {
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
```

Comment: always remember that `=` != `==`

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as the correct one

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to evaluate two `int`s is `==`, not `=`:

```
public static int containsIntElement(int[] A, int val)
    {
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(A[i] == val)   //Note this
            {
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
```

The `=` operator is for assignments, so in

```
if(A[i] = val)
```

You're assigning the value `val` to the variable `A[i]`, that is not a condition

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention to minor details

```
if(A[i] = val) // is incorrect .. in some programming language it is correct. but boy o boy it would make you cry.
if(A[i] == val) // is correct.
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `=` (the assignment operator) where you intended to use `==` (the comparison operator).

What your if does is:
Assign `val` to `A[i]` then try (and fail) to make a logical value from `A[i]`

(naming conventions also say `A` should be lowercase)